# Android TV app doesn't show in the TV Play Store of certain devices

Tags: google-play, android-tv

I have uploaded an app to the play store for TV and the Release Status is Available on Google Play but when I browse through the Device Catalog there are certain devices that are marked as Review Failed. I have noticed a pattern on the chipsets. Those models which have MStar, Realtek and Mediatek as chipsets have been marked as Review Failed. Since most of the TVs have that chipset, this is a major problem for me. Has anybody else faced this problem? If so, what was the solution. Thank you in advance.
[Here is the image of the device catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqyqn.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please extend your question to ask for a specific help? The question right now seems too generic, and it's unclear what is being asked. Could you also add some code snippet, to help identify the issue?

Comment: Hello,
I haven't been able to figure out which part of the code or application is causing this problem. The status for the app in the device catalog says "Review Failed" without any further details on it.

Comment: @ShashankGnawali Is it still Review Failed? Were you able to figure the issue?